# jsoupでのWebサイトの値取得について

Tags: java, web-scraping

[image: エラー内容です]NHKの各都道府県のコロナ人数が出ているページからタグを取り出して、大阪と東京の感染者数を表示させたいです。
実行しても、catchの方にはいかず、結果は出力されません。どの部分を変更すればよろしいでしょうか。`:h3` を表示させるように記述していますが、取ってきたいのは`text`タグの大阪、`1262`です。

```html
<div id="js-slideimage-right01" class="c-slideimage map-test">
  <figure class="js-write-svg">
    <svg class="cls-bg" version="1.1" id="レイヤー_1" ...>

      <!-- 中略 -->

      <g id="グループ_1">
        <g id="グループ_2">

          <!-- 中略 -->

          <g id="近畿">

            <!-- 中略 -->

            <a href="/news/special/coronavirus/data/pref/osaka.html">
              <g data-js-id="大阪府" id="osaka">
                <path data-js-state="" id="path-osaka" class="js-hover cls-yellow" d="M831.6,815.6H717.2v213.6h114.4L831.6,815.6L831.6,815.6z" style="opacity: 1;"></path>
                <text id="osaka-2" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 774.3998 913.7736)" class="st1 st2" text-anchor="middle">大阪</text>
                <text data-name="num" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 774.4001 957.7736)" class="new-infected-val st1 cls-font--s" text-anchor="middle">1262</text>
              </g>
            </a>
```

```java
package useful_function;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
public class Open {
    public void openURLConnection() {

        try {
            // jsoupを使用してトップページへアクセス
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/special/coronavirus/data/").get();

            Elements elements = doc.select("h3");

            for (Element element : elements) {
                System.out.println(element.text());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //      Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        //      try {
        //          r.exec("");
        //      } catch (IOException e) {
        //          System.out.println("開けません");
        //      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/special/coronavirus/data/

のページソースを表示(Google Chromeでは <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>)してみるとわかりますが、取得したコードはそのような形式になっていません。
(Webブラウザに表示されているのは、ページ内のJavaScriptによって加工された結果です。)
従って、jsoupでは意図した加工を行えません。

---

ただし、取得したい情報自体は、そのページのJavaScriptが利用している下記エンドポイントのどちらかから取得できます

- https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/special/coronavirus/data/47newpatients-data.json
- https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/special/coronavirus/data/latest-pref-data.json

ので、例えば [`jackson-databind`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind#3-minute-tutorial-generic-collections-tree-model) を利用して次のような実装で取得可能です。

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class App {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws JsonParseException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        final URL url = new URL("https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/special/coronavirus/data/latest-pref-data.json");
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(url);

        final JsonNode data47 = tree.get("data47");

        // 全県出力
        for (final JsonNode pref : data47) {
            System.out.println(pref.get("name") + ": " + pref.get("new"));
        }

        // 大阪府を抽出
        System.out.println();
        final int count = StreamSupport.stream(data47.spliterator(), false)
            .filter(e -> Objects.equals(e.get("name").asText(), "大阪府"))
            .findFirst()
            .map(e -> e.get("new").asInt())
            .get();

        System.out.println("大阪府: " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: 教えていただいたjackson-databindのjarをダウンロードして、ソースコードを張り付けてみましたが、final JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(url);の部分でエラーが表示されてしまいました。本文の方へエラー一覧を画像で載せました。

Comment: ダウンロードするjarファイルが不足していました。