# 新型コロナ感染者数を記載しているJSONデータがある場所を教えてください

Tags: json, webapi

[jsoupでのWebサイトの値取得について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/75626)

以前この質問をさせてもらい、新型コロナ感染者数の出力プログラムを完成させましたが、現在NHKのサイトの方で使用されていないようで、最終更新日が6月の終わりごろになってしまっています。今はどこから取得しているかを教えていただきたいです。

Comment: プログラムの質問というより、データの取得元に関する内容に見えて、タイトルが内容と一致していない印象です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome dev tools(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>で開ける) の[Networkタブ](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/#load)でアクセス先を見ることができます。
以下がそれぞれ対応する現在のアクセス先だと思います:

- https://www3.nhk.or.jp/n-data/special/coronavirus/data/47newpatients-data.json?stamp=20210621
- https://www3.nhk.or.jp/n-data/special/coronavirus/data/latest-pref-data.json?stamp=20210621

Answer (score 2):

- [NHK の特設ページ](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/special/coronavirus/data/) では CSV 形式でのデータを提供しています。
- もしくは政府の [新型コロナウイルス対策推進室](https://corona.go.jp/dashboard/) では JSON 形式で都道府県別の絞り込みをかけてデータを取得することが可能なようです。